# How to import MYSQL Databse with tables to GoDaddy Cpanel PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to import mysql databse to phpmyadmin of Cpanel in Godaddy, I get fallowing error messsage.

How can I solve it ?

```
Error
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `db_eye_tracking`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db_eye_tracking` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses_ds655uUD97'@'localhost' to database 'db_eye_tracking'
```

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy is a shared server, therefore they impose rules on database naming. Your username is not allowed to create a database with this name.

Use cPanel's MySQL Database wizard: it will tell you what database names are acceptable for your user, to create on their server.

Then you'll have to strip the CREATE DATABASE statement from your file before importing, and other references to this database name.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with a shared hosting account in GoDaddy you have to strip the create database statement in your exported sql file...

## 1007 - Can't create database

#1007 - Can't create database '%dbname%'; database exists

This indicates that you have a query in your SQL file that is
trying to create a database, and since it already exist, it will not
work. Someone must edit the file and remove the CREATE DATABASE query.